# ¿como puedo cambiar el background de un boton en ios?

Tags: ios, swift, botón, layout

Estoy empezando en swift usando el storyboard, tengo abajo un horizontalstackview con unos botones que gestionan los cambios de pantalla. Cuando clico en uno de esos botones, (cada uno tiene una imagen de fondo en gris) me gustaria cambiar la imagen a una a color para saber que estan seleccionados. La imagen desde el storyboard background custom, y en image pongo una de la carpeta assets.
cosas que he probado.

```
if sender.restorationIdentifier == "btnDeportes" {
            let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "deportesAzul")
            sender.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
            print("clikedeportes")
        }
```

no lo establece.
de hecho si miro a ver que hay de imagen de fondo, me da nil.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Si cargas la imagen directamente sin #imageLiteral no funciona?

Comment: nada, realmente lo que hay que hacer para cargarla y que sea "resizable" es como background image, pero bueno al final he desistido y estoy haciendolo de una forma diferente, correcta mas bien.